# API using sails.js in node

Tags: node.js, sails.js, rate-limiting

I have to make an API subscription with the following info provided-

When a user hits any API then as per unique identifier of the user API requests are limited
Such as suppose there are 2 users with different groups - Group1 and Group2
Group1 has a limit of 5 requests per second (RPS) for a particular API (API1)
Group2 has a limit of 6 requests per second (RPS) for the same API (API2).

Any ideas on how to implement this would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have some logic where you can keep data of user group and there limitations and access to set of API endpoints,  use caching database (like redis) for caching and other persistent database of your choice (like mongodb) and in every request have middleware to check limitations and increment access.

Also check below link to understand concepts
https://blog.logrocket.com/rate-limiting-node-js/

Comment: Thanks for the reference it helped alot, I understood how to implement rate limiting for a single user the part where I'm stuck at is how to make user groups?

Comment: visualize the group as a single user, and the problem will be solved. I mean instead of validating a single user validate group and add a user in a group while creating.